# manipulating multiple sum() values in pyspark pivot table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

I'm having a little difficulty in further manipulating a pyspark pivot table to give me a reduced result. My data is a little more complex than the example below, but it's the best example I can come up with to illustrate what I'm trying to do:

Let's say I have a table as follows:

| stock | day | time | hour | price | units | price_x_units |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1:10 | 1 | 2.1 | 3 | 6.3 |
| A | 1 | 1:15 | 1 | 2.0 | 4 | 8.0 |
| A | 2 | 1:03 | 1 | 2.2 | 2 | 4.4 |
| A | 2 | 2:45 | 2 | 1.0 | 4 | 4.0 |
| B | 1 | 2:12 | 2 | 1.2 | 5 | 6.0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |

So the data above represents stock prices that fluctuate in price during the day, and the number of units bought at specific times during that day. I can pivot this as follows:

```
pivotdf = df.groupby("stock", "hour").pivot("day").sum("price_x_units", "units")
```

To give me

| (stock,hour) \ day | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (A,1) | (14.3, 7) | (4.4, 2) | ... | ... |
| (A,2) |  | (4.0, 2) | ... |  |
| (B,2) |  | (6.0,5) |  |  |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

However I want to perform the calculation "price_x_units" / "units" for each resultant cell:

| (stock,hour) \ day | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (A,1) | 2.04 | 2.2 | ... | ... |
| (A,2) |  | 2.0 | ... |  |
| (B,2) |  | 1.2 |  |  |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Further to this, I then want to aggregate (sum) away the stock to give me:

| hour\day | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.04 | 2.2 |  |  |
| 2 |  | 3.2 |  |  |

How exactly do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: `pivotdf = df.groupby("stock", "hour").pivot("day").agg((col("price_x_units") / col("units")).alias("ratio"))` 
`result = pivotdf.groupby("hour").agg(*[sum(col(str(day))).alias(str(day)) for day in range(1, 5)])` 
`result.show()`
Should do the trick for you

Comment: Thanks @Raky. I tried that but the first command gives `AnalysisException: Aggregate expression required for pivot, but 'price_x_units' did not appear in any aggregate function.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the pivot, you could compute the division for each day like this:

```py
# extract the days that are present in the df:
days = set([i.split('_')[0] for i in pivoted_df.columns[2:]])
# you can also just use range(1, 32) if you are sure that all the days are in the df

pivoted_df\
    .select('stock', 'hour',
       *[(F.col(i+'_sum(price_x_units)') / F.col(i+'_sum(units)')).alias(i) for i in days]
    ).show()
```

```
+-----+----+-----------------+----+
|stock|hour|                1|   2|
+-----+----+-----------------+----+
|    A|   1|2.042857142857143| 2.2|
|    A|   2|             null| 1.0|
|    B|   2|              1.2|null|
+-----+----+-----------------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

data = [('A', 1, '1:10', 1, 2.1, 3, 6.3),
        ('A', 1, '1:15', 1, 2.0, 4, 8.0),
        ('A', 2, '1:03', 1, 2.2, 2, 4.4),
        ('A', 2, '2:45', 2, 1.0, 4, 4.0),
        ('B', 1, '2:12', 2, 1.2, 5, 6.0)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["stock", "day", "time", "hour", "price", "units", "price_x_units"])

df = df.withColumn("avg_price", F.col("price_x_units") / F.col("units"))

pivotdf = df.groupby("stock", "hour").pivot("day").agg(F.sum("avg_price"))

pivotdf.show()

result = pivotdf.groupBy("hour").sum()
result = result.drop("stock").orderBy("hour")

result.show()
```